# Java: LinkedList class as stack and queues

Tags: java, class, linked-list, stack, queue

I am new to LinkedList class, and facing difficulties as to how to use it in order to implement or instantiate stack and queues object. I am not looking for piece of self-implemented codes.

I wanted to know how do we use this class as stack and queues and can use the already defined methods: pop,push,enqueue and dequeue or top (in case of stacks).

Comment: [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) already has `push()`, `pop()`, `getFirst()`, `getLast()`, etc. You can directly map them to the usual queue and stack operations.

Comment: `LinkedList` can be used as a stack or queue by using the methods it provides. Go read the [api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)

Comment: @JFMeier `LinkedList` is a much more suitable class to use in this case than an `ArrayList`

Comment: It may be easier to use, but it is slow compared to solutions based on ArrayList (a Stack can be easily implemented by storing the index of the top element, a queue needs an ArrayList which is "circular" as in the GapList implementation).

Comment: @JFMeier A linked list can add and remove items to and from either end without requiring any resizing or shuffling of elements. It is a more suitable choice for a stack or queue than an `ArrayList`.

Comment: I cannot prove my point and neither can you. I can only say that replacing LinkedList by ArrayList nearly always improved the speed in the applications I have seen, even if a lot of adding and removing of elements occured. My guess is that the aligned memory of an ArrayList can be used more efficiently than the spread-out memory of a LinkedList.

Comment: @khelwood For pure stack and queue operations, `ArrayDeque` is usually the preferred choice.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Queue

A `LinkedList` is already a queue, since it implements the `Queue` interface (and check the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) yourself).  Hence it has the following queue operations:

**enqueue:**

```
add() - Appends the specified element to the end of this list.
```

**dequeue:**

```
remove() - Retrieves and removes the head (first element) of this list.
```

## Stack

It is also very easy to use a `LinkedList` as a stack, since it has a method `removeLast()` which can remove an item from the end of the list (rather than the start, which `remove()` does:

**push:**

```
add() - Appends the specified element to the end of this list.
```

**pop:**

```
removeLast() - Removes and returns the last element from this list.
```

Appending and removing always from the end of the list simulates a stack, which is a LIFO (Last in first out) data structure.

Comment: While using LL as a stack, we can also use push and pop methods of LinkedList. Doing so would mean that its more clear that this LinkedList is being used as a stack coz of push and pop method names.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, `which is a FIFO (first in first out) data structure.` Is this should be LIFO for a stack? Queue would be FIFO.

Answer (score 4):

If you take a look at the implemented interfaces, then [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) is a drop-in implementation for queues.

[`Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) is not an interface in java, but a class. LinkedList doesn't contain the `peek()`, `empty()` and `search()` methods, so it's not a fully-fledged stack. Still, it can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but it bit me.  But i also caution replacement of a Stack.  While some, like LinkedList, provide push, pop, and peak - the items are placed in the list in different order.  LinkedList works off the front end, Stack works off the back.  So, if iterating the list, they are reversed.  so be careful ...